# Cypress - How to check the text of table subrows alongside normal rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, cucumber, cypress

I have a table that structurally looks something like this

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="first-col">--</td>
            <td class="second-col">--</td>
            <td class="third-col">--</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="first-col">--</td>
            <td class="second-col">--</td>
            <td class="third-col">--</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="first-col">
                <div>
                    <span class="sub-row">--</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="sub-row">--</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="sub-row">--</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="second-col">
                <div>
                    <span class="sub-row">--</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="sub-row">--</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="sub-row">--</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="third-col">
                <div>
                    <span class="sub-row">--</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="sub-row">--</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="sub-row">--</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like to write a cypress test (cucumber) that verifies that each entry in the first column is equal to '--'. I started with something like this

```js
Then('The first column displays -- in every row', function () {
    cy.get(this.base).find('.first-col').each(($row) => {
        expect($row.text().trim()).to.equal('--');
    });
});
```

But of course that will concatenate the sub-rows and produce something like this when evaluating the third row

```
AssertionError
    + expected - actual

    -'--  --  --'
    +'--'
```

So I attempted to set up a simple check for sub-rows before expecting

```js
Then('The first column displays -- in every row', function () {
    cy.get(this.base).find('.first-col').each(($row) => {
        const subRows = $row.find('.sub-row');
        if (subRows.length) {
            subRows.each(($subRow) => {
                expect($subRow.text().trim()).to.equal('--')
            });
        } else {
            expect($row.text().trim()).to.equal('--');
        }
    });
});
```

My thinking being that each `$row` corresponds to a `tr class="first-col"`, `subRows` corresponds to an array of the `span class="sub-row"` elements in a given `$row` (if any), and then by iterating through the individual `$subRow`s in `subRows`, I can assert on each of them.

The problem is that cypress is not recognizing `$subRow` as something it can perform functions on.

```
TypeError: $subRow.text is not a function
```

But it has no problem with the `else` part of the conditional that runs on the prior rows, which has very similar logic. It's not until the row with the subrows that it fails.

[image]

I have to imagine that I have a conceptual misunderstanding about what gets returned by `.each()`, or `.find()`, or both. Or maybe it's because the element is a `span` instead of a `td`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fix is to wrap `subrows`.

```js
cy.get('tr').find('.first-col').each(($row) => {
  const subRows = $row.find('.sub-row');
  if (subRows.length) {

    // wrap subrows variable to allow use of Cypress .each() command
    cy.wrap(subRows).each(($subRow) => {
      expect($subRow.text().trim()).to.equal('--')
    });

  } else {
    expect($row.text().trim()).to.equal('--');
  }
});
```

---

`subrows` is a jQuery object. If you look at the [jQuery.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) docs you'll see that the callback has parameters `function( index, value )`, whereas the Cypress command `.each()` has parameters the other way round `.each(($el, index, $list) => {`.

The Cypress version is probably more convenient to use in this test.

Comment: So you're saying without wrapping it was treating it as a jQuery object, but by using cy.wrap() I can treat it as a cypress object? Wrapping subRows did not change the error message, so I want to make sure I understand the concept behind your suggestion.

Comment: That's a pretty good summary, yes. I actually ran the HTML to make sure I had the right code, and it worked for me. Is there any other factor not given above?

Comment: The `each()` overload is good to know but hard to keep track of. I'd love better IDE support for cypress.

The example above is really a pretty close approximation of my actual code. I'm struggling to find anything different...

Comment: Likely you would get that with Typescript.

Comment: I found the error! It was a minor syntactical error resulting from messy experimental code. Once I cleaned it up, the wrap was indeed the solution. Thanks!